# How to load a properties file put in the classpath from a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a properties file which I have put in the classpath and I am trying to load it from a JSP:

```
InputStream stream = application.getResourceAsStream("/alert.properties"); 
Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.load(stream);
```

But I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: What path have you placed alert.properties ?

Answer (score 2):

The [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) returns resources from the webcontent, not from the classpath. You need [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("filename.properties"));
// ...
```

---

That said, it is considered bad practice to write raw Java code like that in a JSP file. You should be doing that (in)directly inside a `HttpServlet` or maybe a `ServletContextListener` class.

Comment: +1 - it is also inefficient to (I assume) repeatedly reload the same properties file each time a JSP is executed.